# Prevent SwiftUI scrollview scrolling when interacting with a specific component

Tags: ios, swiftui, scroll, scrollview

I am trying to add a PKCanvasView to a scrollview with SwiftUI.
But when I try to draw in the PKCanvasView it scrolls the scrollview instead.

In other words, how could I deactivate the scrolling when the user interacts with a specific view inside the scrollview?

I parsed through a lot of examples and blog articles and almost similar things but they were either too old or not for SwiftUI...

**EDIT**
To give further details (and based on Guillermo answer), here is an additional sample:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scrollDisabled = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {

                    ForEach(1..<50) { i in

                        Rectangle()
                            .fill((i & 1 == 0) ? .blue: .yellow)
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                            .overlay {
                                Text("\(i)")
                            }
                    }
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .scrollDisabled(scrollDisabled)
        }
        .frame(width: 300)
    }
}
```

[image]

Note that you cannot scroll touching the leading/trailing white borders.
I'd like the same behavior for yellow items: if you try to move up/down while touching a blue cell it scrolls, but if you try the same with yellow the scrollview shouldn't scroll!

Sorry, I'm really trying my best to be clear... ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control how your elements respond to the drag gesture with the following:

```
.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance:))
```

For instance:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {

                    ForEach(1..<50) { i in

                        Rectangle()
                            .fill((i & 1 == 0) ? .blue: .yellow)
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                            .overlay {
                                Text("\(i)")
                            }
                            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: i & 1 == 0 ? 100 : 0))
                    }
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300)
    }
}
```

will block the scrolling for the yellow elements!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 16 was added a modifier `scrollDisabled` to achieve what you need here's an example:

```
struct Scroll: View {
    @State private var scrollDisabled = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("\(scrollDisabled ? "Enable" : "Disable") Scroll") {
                scrollDisabled.toggle()
            }
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    
                    ForEach(1..<50) { i in
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(.blue)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .overlay {
                                Text("\(i)")
                            }
                    }
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .scrollDisabled(scrollDisabled)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's close to what I am looking for, thank you!

But I don't want to deactivate the entire scroll, your sample is great to start from:

For instance, if I want that the user scroll the scrollview when sliding an even number but not when touching an odd one?

It is the case when you have a date picker in a scrollview: interacting with the date picket doesn't scroll the scrollview behind...