# How to prevent scrolling when interacting with a PKCanvasView in a Scroll view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, user-input, gesture, pkcanvasview

I have a UIViewRepresentable that represents a PKCanvasView.

```
struct PKCanvasRepresentable : UIViewRepresentable
{
    @Binding var canvas: PKCanvasView
 
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        canvas.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .black, width: 2)
        canvas.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
        canvas.isOpaque = false
        canvas.backgroundColor = .clear
        return canvas
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {}
}
```

I want to use it as part of a sheet, that contains other input components and must be vertically scrollable.

```
@State var canvas = PKCanvasView()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                // ..various components..
                PKCanvasRepresentable(canvas: $canvas)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The drawing does not work, because the drawing gesture gets canceled by the scroll gesture.

---

**I would like the PKCanvasView related gestures having priority over the scroll view ones. How can i achieve this?**

---

**Example**

The expected behaviour can be seen when - for example - a DatePicker in wheel style is in a ScrollView. The scroll view does not receive any gesture input when interacting with the DatePicker. I would like to have the same behaviour for a PKCanvasView.

---

**Additional info**

- I tried to add various Gesture modifiers to the Representable which prevents the ScrollView from getting input events - but of course that also prevents the Canvas from getting user input.
- I built a drawing component myself in the past which worked, because i had control over the Gestures that were added to make the component happen. But i would prefer to use PKCanvasView, which does everything i need already - except from the described issue.
- I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75376913/prevent-swiftui-scrollview-scrolling-when-interacting-with-a-specific-component) - but it has nothing to do with PKCanvasView and its solution does not help.
- I tried ai based code generators - but i don't have any subscriptions so i'm limited in tries and length of the answer. I tried the following quote, which produced only invalid, tutorial level answers:

> Write a SwitUI view that contains of a ScrollView which has a nested UIViewRepresentable of a PKCanvasView where the ScrollView does not receive any kind of user input, events or gestures while the user interacts with the PKCanvasView and tries to draw but functions normally whenever the user does not interact with the PKCanvasView